# Publisher confirm / publisher returns / AmqpConnectException not working

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm using rabbitMqTemplate's convertAndSend method to publish a message. If I don't have rabbitMq server running, I would expect the call to throw an exception which it does not.

I have setup the connection factory like so

```
@Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        connectionFactory.setUsername(rabbitProperties.getUsername());
        connectionFactory.setPassword(rabbitProperties.getPassword());
        connectionFactory.setPort(rabbitProperties.getPort());
        connectionFactory.setPublisherConfirms(true);
        connectionFactory.setPublisherReturns(true);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }
```

I send the message like this

```
this.rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback((correlationData, ack, cause) -> {
                LOGGER.debug("RabbitMq could not send the message");
});
this.rabbitTemplate.setReturnCallback((message, replyCode, replyText, exchange, routingKey) -> {
                LOGGER.debug("RabbitMq return callback : " + replyCode);
});
this.rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchangeName, routing, deliverable, new CorrelationData(correlationId));
```

I want to take some action if convertAndSend does not successfully publish the message to Queue. How can I do this?

Thanks,
Sudha

Comment: Please explain further or provide a project that exhibits this behavior; I get `Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)`.